# Relationship of Function object and Javascript object

Tags: javascript

Recently I read a [tutorial](http://kevinoncode.blogspot.com/2011/04/understanding-javascript-inheritance.html) which says if define the function like below.

```
function Animal() { }
```

> On the surface, this code seems to create a function called Animal.
>   But with JavaScript, the full truth is slightly more complicated. What
>   actually happens when this code executes is that two objects are
>   created. The first object, called Animal, is the constructor function
>   itself. The second object, called Animal.prototype, has a property
>   called Animal.prototype.constructor, which points to Animal. Animal
>   has a property which points back to its prototype, Animal.prototype.

But I have little confuse about it .What about the `Function` object ?What is the use for the `Animal` object?

And If I write code like below .

```
var test= new Function();
```

and I inspected the variable `test` in the Developer tool of the Chrome.
I found `test` is nothing to do with the `Function`. Can someone tell me why ? thanks.

[image]

**Updated**

The diagram below is the objects relationship when the code is executed, please review it.
If my understanding is wrong. please correct me. thanks.

[image: If my understanding is wrong. please correct me. thanks.]

Comment: The variable "test" is a reference to the `Function` object.  That's clear from what you posted; note that the value of "test" is `function anonymous() {}`

Comment: :)  I was confused by what exactly the `test` is a `Function` object or `test` object ?(from the definition we can see it is created an object named `test`.) .

Comment: It's an object, and specifically an object constructed by the `Function` constructor.  There's no such thing as a "test" object in your example code.  If, after setting "test" as you did, you then wrote `var test2 = new test();`, then "test2" would refer to an object constructed by "test".

Comment: Also I think that blog post you're looking at involves an unnecessary amount of detail.

Comment: But the blog post said `... when this code executes is that two objects are created. ` the words `executes` means to call the `new` like you said?

Comment: It's true that two objects are created: the `Function` instance, and its prototype object.  The prototype object is a property of the `Function` object. The value of the `new Function()` expression is a reference to the `Function` object, not the prototype.

Comment: hm..little complicated . :)

Comment: @Pointy  Can I say `test._proto_` is `Function.prototype` ?

Comment: Well, `test.__proto__` is the prototype object of the function object that you created. The `Function` constructor has its *own* prototype object.

Comment: +1 for a question where someone is trying to learn something instead of just do something :) This may seem completely irrelevant, but it would make sense if you followed my train of thought. Anyways, if you're up for a bit of a gamble, [check out this link](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions) and see if it helps with the concept of `function Animal() { ... }` as three separate functions (with more nested functions within). It might also very much not help..

Comment: @asifrc I totally can't understand the blog you post ....It is not `js` code ..

Comment: haha, then just ignore it.. I'm still mulling it over myself..

Comment: @Pointy Please let me take an example . If I defined a method named `hello` for the Function instance, I think I can make it by writing the code as 'Function.prototype.hello=function(){alert('hello')};', But I don't know how `test` find the `hello` . If the `test._proto_ != Function.prototype` as you said.

Comment: @asifrc  +1 for that I agree with you the attitude of leaning something .

Comment: All newly created functions inherit from the Function prototype, (when  they are invoked with ``function bar(){}`` or ``var foo = new Function()``, which is why both ``bar`` and ``foo`` can use the ``hello`` method. Basically, what @pointy said earlier :) Also, this seems like it is better suited to a chat / forum format than a question at this point.

Comment: Wait - sorry, I think it was me who was confused a couple of comments ago :-)  I think that `test.__proto__` really would be `Function.prototype`. However, note that the `__proto__` property really isn't a standard; it's not something you should rely on, and really it's pretty rare that you have to worry about such details.

Comment: I think some of these comments would be more appropriate as answers than comments.. This is getting quite chatty..

Comment: Someone can post a answer for all the confuse and detail ? there are too many comments not convenient to read. thanks.

Comment: @Pointy :)  ... Always make us confused..Better to post a answer to summary the details . thanks.

Comment: Answer posted. It would probably be a lot easier to get clear answers if you tried a few test programs. If something in your test program does something you don't understand, you can ask about that. It's easier to discuss concrete examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That blog post goes into a lot of detail that's interesting but unnecessarily confusing for most people most of the time.

First, let's talk about functions; forget about prototypes for a minute. When you create a function:

```
function Whatever() {
  // ...
}
```

you've created an object.  That is, all functions are objects, and they're constructed via the `Function` built-in constructor.  The symbol "Whatever" in this example will have as its value a reference to that object.

Given a reference to a function, it's possible to call it:

```
Whatever(); // call the function
```

It's possible to take that value (the reference to the function object) and assign it to another variable, or pass it as a parameter to another function, or to use it just like any other value in JavaScript.

```
var another = Whatever;
another(); // also calls the "Whatever" function
```

Constructing a function via the `Function` constructor explicitly is something that's rarely done, but it gives you a function that's otherwise unremarkable. (In the OP, the constructed function doesn't do anything because no code was passed to the `Function` constructor.)

Now, things get interesting when a function is invoked as part of a `new` expression.

```
var test = new Whatever();
```

By using `new`, a new object is instantiated and associated with the "Whatever" function. The "Whatever" function is the constructor for that new object.

Every function object, whether it's ever used as a constructor or not, has an associated "prototype" object.  When a function *is* used as a constructor, then objects it constructs (that is, objects made in `new` expressions that invoke the function) are implicitly associated with that prototype object.

The prototype object becomes interesting when an object property reference expression is evaluated. Object property references look like this:

```
obj.name
obj[ nameExpression ]
```

In such an expression, the property name (either the identifier used in the `.` expression or the value of the expression inside `[ ]`) is checked against the set of properties on the object directly. If the name is not the same as one of the object's properties, then the runtime consults the prototype object associated with the constructor function used to make the object.

For most code that most people write, that relationship and some of its direct implications are the only things to worry about. You don't have to fool around with the (non-standard, at this time) "**proto**" property of objects unless you're putting together some sort of library or framework.

Finally, it might be instructive to look at the [`Object.create()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) and in particular the "polyfill" shown in that documentation.